# Is it possible to get the actual diffs from the vscode.diff command

Tags: vscode-extensions

I can relatively easily cause vscode to open up a new diff view by calling `commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff", left.uri, right.uri, "MyDiff")` and even get some information by inspecting the active tab after that. However I want to do some actions based on those diffs (effectively accepting/rejecting the differences between the documents similarly to the git scm view) and I'm struggling to find if there is any place that the diffs themselves are actually available.

The code to generate them appears to live inside https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/src/vs/editor/common/diff but I similarly can't identify a way to call any of this.